# $this->set('title', 'Title Name'); not working in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Basically in default.ctp I have this for my title:

```
<title>
  <?= $this->fetch('title') ?>
</title>
```

And inside of the controller I have this line:

```
$this->set('title', 'Test-Title');
```

But it does nothing, it still displays controllers name(Jobs, controllers full name os JobsController.ctp)

But if I put this inside of my view file:

```
$this->assign('title', 'Test-Title');
```

It changes the title. So what is wrong with $this->set('title', $title) **?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just `set()` the variable in your controller:

```
// View or Controller
$this->set('title', 'Test-title');
```

Then use it as a standard variable is in your layout or view:

```
<!-- Layout or View -->
<title>
    <?php echo $title; ?>
</title>
```

Details here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#setting-view-variables

Using `assign()` is different, which is why it works with `fetch()`.  `assign()` is used with View Blocks:  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks

Comment: Yes, I know that I can do this inside of the view, but I want to do it inside of the Controller, it should be working inside of the controller as well, but it doesn't

Comment: Same goes for controller - don't `fetch()` it, just use it.

Comment: Instead php echo, you can use shorter ctp expression <?= $title ?>

Answer (score 24):

`fetch()` returns the contents of a block not a variable. Using `set()` in your Controller is setting a variable that can be output in your View templates by echoing the variable:-

```
<?php echo $title; ?>
```

If you want to use `fetch()` you need to use it in combination with `assign()` in the View templates to define the block. For example in your View template use:-

```
<?php $this->assign('title', $title); ?>
```

And then in the layout template:-

```
<title><?php echo $this->fetch('title'); ?></title>
```

In CakePHP 3 the idea is to set the page title by assigning it in the View as it relates to the rendering of the page. This differs from how this was originally handled in CakePHP 2 where you'd define `title_for_layout` in your controller and then echo the `$title_for_layout` variable in the layout template (this was deprecated in favour of the CakePHP 3 approach in later versions of Cake 2).

Comment: Side note, the default `title` block value is assigned in [**`Cake\View\View::renderLayout()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.View.View.html#477-513), it's being derived from the `View::$viewPath` value.

Answer (score 3):

In CakePHP 3 layout template, make sure to set the title as below.

```
<title>
    <?= $this->fetch('title') ?>    
</title>
```

Then in your view:

```
<?php $this->assign('title', 'Title Name'); ?>
```

This is the way CakePHP will use its built-in View classes for handling page title (view blocks) rendering scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion, I came across a situation where a malformed .js script with undefined variables referenced between `<head></head>` resulted in the `<title></title>` tags being posted to DOM (showed in page source) but *Chrome, Firefox* and (from memory) *MSIE* **all** failed to deliver the content of the title to the APP UI, again from memory - *iOS mobile* was unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want stick to your code, after setting "title" variable just simply write this:

```
    <?= __('Main Project Name') ?>
    <?php if( isset($title)) $this->assign('title', $title); ?>
    <?= ' - ' . $this->fetch('title') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, this way in `default.ctp`

```
<?php
    $cakeDescription = __d('cake_dev', 'Your Title');
?>

<title>
    <?php echo $cakeDescription ?>: <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
</title>
```

In my view file, I have done this.

```
<?php $this->assign('title', 'Your Title');?>
```