# Using Meta Description in the right place CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, metadata, smarty, head, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to use meta tags and description in cakephp 3. It is working so far, but I am facing the problem that I can´t put it in the  of my page, because my .ctp files are rendered in my default.ctp

So for example I have my menu, footer etc. in my default.ctp and my page for the faq is in the faq.ctp How can I push those

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->meta('description','enter any meta description here');
?>
```

metadescription in the head tag? Do I need a template language like smarty and use blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In layout:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->meta('description',$description);
?
```

in your faq.ctp or faq() method:

```
<?php
$this->set('description','enter any meta description here');
?
```

Comment: Wow, so simple! Thanks a lot @Salines!!

Answer (score 2):

add this in your `ctp` file (**there is NO echo** )

```
<?php $this->Html->meta('description', 'some text here', ['block' => true]);?>
```

and this line into your layout

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('meta');?>
```

see also similar question with title: [$this->set('title', 'Title Name'); not working in CakePHP 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171030/this-settitle-title-name-not-working-in-cakephp-3-x/30171406#30171406)